# How to add different items to a Page View Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I have this code which allows me to scroll between cards that hold text.  However, all it does is add the same text on each card.  I want to display two separate pieces of text which are kept inside

```
HomeInfo()
Achieve()
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
SizedBox(
                    height: 300,
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2,
                        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7),
                        onPageChanged: (int index) =>
                            setState(() => _index = index),
                        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                          return Transform.scale(
                            scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 6,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                              child: Center(
                                child: HomeInfo(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

I am really confused on how to do this. (I just started getting into coding)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the index and return the appropriate widget.

**You can achieve this way:**

```
SizedBox(
                    height: 300,
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2,
                        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7),
                        onPageChanged: (int index) =>
                            setState(() => _index = index),
                        itemBuilder: (_, i) {

                          return Transform.scale(
                            scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 6,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                              child: Center(
                                child: i == 0 ? HomeInfo() : Achieve(), // this line
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have to wait six minutes to accpet it as an answer, but I will do that.

Comment: You're most welcome. Take your time. No worries. :)